# Intelli J IDEA Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8787): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am trying for remote debugging a java test file in intelli J IDEA.But i am getting following error.

> Error running 'test': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8787):
>   java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally
>   closed"

I have seen solutions of editing command line argument, but it does not allow in 2019.2(ultimate edition).

Below is my configuration.

[image: Blockquote]

please help.

Comment: how do you run your java file/project?

Comment: Actually i am trying to run a java test file from dockerized container using ant.

command is ===>>

ant test-single -DremoteDebug=true -Dtestcase=helloTest

Comment: you need to add the `-agentlib...` line as command line argument

Comment: its already there at start in command line.And as i mentioned , it does not allow me to edit anything in command line argument block

Comment: What is the output of the command `docker ps` for that specific container? Specifically the PORTS column?

Comment: The `Command line argument for remote JVM` is what you need to start the remote JVM with. It's nothing you edit in Intellij.

Answer (score 2):

The `java` command that is running in the container needs to have the following parameter, together with any other parameters already there.

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8787
```

When the image for the container is created, port 8787 needs to be exposed by adding the following line in `Dockerfile`:

```
EXPOSE 8787
```

When you create the container, you need to specify that port 8787 should be tunneled to your docker host. If you are using `docker-compose` add the following under the specific container section:

```
ports:
  - '8787:8787'
```

If you are using `docker create` the parameter is `--publish=8787:8787`.

If all this has been setup correctly it should now be possible for the debugger to connect to localhost:8787.